# How to separate a column containing multiple values ​per row into many columns

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

Goodmorning everyone.

I have a big dataframe, in particular I have a column (a list) containing from 5 to 15 elements. I would like to divide it into many
columns how many are the elements of each row of the column.

```
    A                  B                 JHON
   GREEN    c("abc", "def", "ghi")       yellow
   RED      c("123", "456", "789")       blue
   JACK     d("rgy", "bob", "pbc")       pink
```

I would like to achieve such a thing

```
    A          B       C       D    JHON
  GREEN       abc      def    ghi   yellow
  RED         123      456    789   blue
  JACK        rgy      bob    pbc   pink


ah <- c("A", "B", "C")

separate(df , unlist(df$B), ah )
```

i tried to set such a thing but i get the error below

```
Errore: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 5322 but must be size 1.
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.
I add the column of my interest

```
 ProductGallery = list(
    c("http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_3828389912.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_0985217712.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_2053118492.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_3136121979.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_3698859043.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_7403185164.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_5829735672.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_1378074619.jpg", 
    "http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/15656565_9686454727.jpg",
```

Comment: Please paste an example of your data using `dput(head(YourData)`. You can limit your example just to the columns needed for this question. Why am I asking for data? I'm not sure, what structure is contained in column `B`, but that's important for solving your problem.

Comment: @Martin Gal I am honored to be helped by an actuary (I have the exam next Thursday).
The dataframe consists of 500 rows by 300 columns. I performed your function and the result being very large, youI glue the column we are talking about.

Comment: Good Luck for your exam! You can try `df %>% unnest(B)` and then performe some `pivot_wider`.

Comment: The data shared is incomplete. Can you add output of `dput(head(df))` to your post?

Comment: @Ronak Shah I wrote you an email

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
df$C <- df$B[2]
df$D <- df$B[3]
df$B <- df$B[1]
```